# How to pause carousel in bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to click a button that pauses a Bootstrap 5 carousel.

The pause is not working.

I have a [Code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/davodotnet/pen/KKNoYwj) and repeated the code below as well.

```js
document.getElementById("btnPause").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var carouselElement = document.getElementById("carouselAnimals");
  var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(carouselElement);
  carousel.pause(); // seems to get called, but doesn't pause

  // carousel('pause'); // doesn't work
  // carousel.carousel('pause'); // doesn't work
});
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <button id='btnPause' class="btn btn-secondary">Stop carousel</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
            <div id="carouselAnimals" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval='1000' data-interval='100' >
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/800/500" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/800/500" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="http://placeimg.com/800/500/animals" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You instantiate on every button click. In short words, your "click" and "new Carousel" should be in reverse order. Attach the click event after you have an instance. Just like in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the way you are trying to do results in two different carousel instances.

1. the one you see, which is scrolling is automatically created by bootstrap
2. the second one you are creating when pressing your button

But the second one is not rendered anywhere.

So in order to make it stop, initialise it yourself before pressing the button like so:

```
var carouselElement = document.getElementById("carouselAnimals");

/* it looks like manually initialising the carousel
   will overwrite html data-attributes, so you have to
   specify properties when creating the slider */

var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(carouselElement, {
  interval: 100
});

document.getElementById("btnPause").addEventListener("click", function () {
  carousel.pause();
});
```

Working example (JSFiddle, sorry don't have a codepen account):
https://jsfiddle.net/y5z98xfe/

Comment: Thank you @Hoargarth, I thought the issue might have been related to something like that, I was following online examples that worked like that, but I'll go and alter my code and then get back to you.

Comment: I'm using a newer version of Bootstrap (5.2.3) with custom code that follows the same principle as this example, but it doesn't work. For the constructor, I'm passing `ride: "carousel"` as an option. This produces a carousel that autoplays. Next, I assign the "click" event to each arrow. I've verified that when I click the arrows the "pause" method gets called, but the carousel doesn't stop autoplaying. Is it because I'm adding the "click" listener to the arrows? Do I need to make a custom pause button?

Comment: Sorry, here's my CodePen example: https://codepen.io/will_beaumont/pen/MWxWGbK

Comment: @WilliamBeaumont it looks like the standard behaviour for the carousel is to resume the autoplay when clicking next/prev buttons. So first your event is pausing it, but the standard functionality immediately resumes it. I couldn't find anything to actually pause it with your codepen (but haven't really used the recent versions). But what did work for me was setting the interval time to a very high amount -> `carousel._config.defaultInterval = 9999999;     carousel._config.interval = 9999999;`. Note that you have to change the `defaultInterval` as well or your `interval` gets overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and adding `data-bs-pause="false"` to the carousel fixed it for me. For example...

```
<div id="carouselAnimals" class="carousel slide" data-bs-pause="false">
...
</div>
```

When I was reading about the [`pause`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#options) option, I learned the default value of `"hover"` causes the carousel to resume after the mouse leaves the area, sometimes giving the illusion that it never actually pauses.

Once I set `data-bs-pause="false"` on my element, calling `carousel.pause()` worked as expected.